# Permutational Primes Kata optimatization

Tags: ruby, permutation, primes

I am solving the Permutational Primes Kata using Ruby. I manage to find out Brute-force solution but it exceeds the time limits. I need to optimize my code but I don't have any idea how to do this. The [Kata](https://www.codewars.com/kata/55eec0ee00ae4a8fa0000075/train/ruby).

```
 require 'prime'

def permutational_primes(n_max, k_perms)
  result_h = {}
  result_keys = []
  Prime.each(n_max) do |prime|
      perms = prime.digits.permutation.to_a.map(&:join).map(&:to_i).uniq
      prime_no_length = prime.to_s.length
      perms = perms.delete_if { |el| el.to_s.length < prime_no_length  }
      # elimianate number greater than n_max
      perms = perms.delete_if { |el| el > n_max }
    
      next if (perms & result_keys).any?
 
      perms = perms.delete_if { |el| !Prime.prime?(el) }
      
      # minus one because we include 
      if perms.count - 1 == k_perms
        result_h[prime] = perms
        result_keys.append(prime)
      end
  end

    return [0, 0, 0] if result_keys.empty?
    [result_h.count, result_keys[0], result_keys[result_keys.count-1]]
end
```

Comment: Using Prime.each, precompute a table of all primes up to `n_max` as the first step. The table should be `n_max` long and be such that table[x] is true if and only if x is a prime. Then iterate over the permutations, and each check for primality only costs a single table lookup

Answer (score 0):

Some low-hanging fruit:

- Benchmarking is one way to understand what parts are more computationally expensive than others (likely `Prime.prime?`)
- Find work that you're doing repeatedly or checks for information that you already know every `Prime.each` loop and cache it, trading memory for computation, e.g. `Prime.prime?`
- All the common `Enumerable` methods create new `Array`s. Instead, reuse existing arrays, e.g. `map!`

Answer (score 0):

I have not yet thoroughly tested the following, but this general approach should speed things up considerably. There are two main elements that improved efficiency: use of the method [Prime::each](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/prime/rdoc/Prime.html#method-i-each) and maintaining a set of prime permutations already tested, to avoid unnecessary testing of duplicates.

```
require 'prime'
require 'set'

def permutational_primes(nMax, permutes)
  skips = Set.new
  enum = Prime.each
  arr = []
  while (prime = enum.next) < nMax
    next if skips.include?(prime)
    a = prime.digits.permutation.with_object([]) do |perm,a|
      next if perm[-1].zero?
      n = perm.reverse.join.to_i
      if n < nMax && !skips.include?(n) && Prime.prime?(n)
        skips << n
        a << n
      end 
    end
    a.each { |n| skips << n }
    next if a.size != permutes + 1
    arr << a.min
  end
  [arr.size, arr.size.zero? ? 0 : arr.min, arr.size.zero? ? 0 : arr.max]
end
```

```
permutational_primes(1000, 3)
  #=> [3, 149, 379]
```

This passes all tests but times out. I'm working on another optimization.

Explanation is under construction...